# Multiple parallel MSys/MingW installations on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, bash

when installing MSysgit, also MSys (as the name suggests) is installed on my machine.
When I additionally install DevKit for Ruby, yet another copy of MSys is installed on my computer. When installing the Haskell Platform for Windows, again another copy of MSys is installed on my machine. Is there any way of installing MSys/mingw once and tell all other software to do a lookup in the Path?

Comment: It is up to the installer for each application to verify if prerequisites are installed beforehand. You could try opening a bug with the installers that do not use existing copies of msys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of msys that is included in the Git for Windows package is modified and if you attempt to replace it with a stock msys package you will run into problems. I can't comment on the other packages but basically - it is not worth worrying about. Disk space is significantly cheaper than the time you spend trying to make a number of independent packages share a common msys platform.

However, there are in fact people working on trying to sort that out. msys now has a package management system and I know of at least one project attempting to get the Git for Windows build environment working withing that system [mingwGitDevEnv](https://github.com/sschuberth/mingwGitDevEnv).